# How to include node module in static js

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, node-modules, hugo

Installed a node package via `npm i resize-start-end -S'`.

This is the instruction provided by the package:

```
// ESM
import resizeStartEnd from 'resize-start-end';

// or CommonJS
const resizeStartEnd = require('resize-start-end');
```

I'm trying to include the package in a JS file in my hugo static directory. None of the above works (can't be found).

My js is located in `static/src/js` and gulp will concat it into `static/js`.

Advice appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

From Hugo version 0.56 you can use [Hugo mounts](https://gohugo.io/hugo-modules/configuration/#module-config-mounts).

After module install (`npm i your-module -S`)

Add to your config file (*json format for example*):

```
"module": {
    "mounts": [
       {
        "source": "node_modules",
        "target": "static/src/node_modules"
       }
    ]
}
```

Then you can use in your scripts in src directory:

```
import * as yourModule from './node_modules/your-module/index.js'
```